# Changing HTML child tags to siblings in Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have some HTML code which consists of `<option>` tags inside a select tag, however, the option tags are descendants of each other, but I want them to be siblings (direct children of the select tag).

What the HTML looks like now:

```
<select>
    <option> Option 1
        <option> Option 2
            <option> Option3  
                <option> Option 4
                    etc...
                </option>
            </option>
        </option>
    </option>
</select>
```

And what I would like it to look like:

```
<select>
    <option> Option 1 </option>
    <option> Option 2 </option>
    <option> Option 3 </option>
    <option> Option 4 </option>
    etc.
</select>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup corrects it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('''<html>
    <body>
        <select>
            <option>Option 1
                <option>Option 2
                    <option>Option3  
                        <option>Option 4
                        </option>
                    </option>
                </option>
            </option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>''')

print(soup)
```

print

```
<html>
<body>
<select>
<option>Option 1
                </option><option>Option 2
                    </option><option>Option3
                        </option><option>Option 4
                        </option>
</select>
</body>
</html>
```